# how to add new buddy in roster in xmpp

Tags: xmpp, smack

Hi i am using smack.jar.I am able to connect with gtalk using it.Using `Roster.getentries()` i can get my buddy list.But how can i add new friends to my buddyList.Is there any API smack exposes to add new users??

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been using this to create new contacts in a standard XMPP server (can't tell about gtalk):

```
  Roster roster = xmppConnection.getRoster();
  // jid: String, user: String, groups: String[]
  roster.createEntry(jid, user, groups);
```

Comment: You'll probably want to listen for inbound subscription requests as well, since when you subscribe to someone, they often subscribe back.

Comment: how the friend will listen that he or she has been added to someones list or someone wants to add him as friend.. Please reply @JoeHildebrand

Answer (score 5):

In XMPP, adding is adding to your roster + subscribing to the user. Updating is just adding the user to your roster. Keep in mind the minutiae.